# join two columns from two csv files in Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am new to **pandas** and got a problem:
I have 2 csv files with same `column name` i.e `account_key`, now number of unique values of `account_key` in **csv A** is suppose `1000` whereas number of unique values of `account_key` in **csv B** is `950` so data is missing in **csv B**

I am trying to create a table/column somewhat like:

```
   account_key(form csv A)     account_key(from csv B)
0   448                         448
1   448                         448
```

so that I can see or know where data is missing

Please guide

any trick or another easy/simple method with **Pandas** will be appreciated.

> using Python3 and Ipython

Answer (score 0):

Python has isnull() function to detect missisng values.SO I think that you should try something like this

```
pd.isnull(csv B)
```

After that you will have a clear picture of your data status.